# Image with text caption in a fixed-sized div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm facing a CSS/HTML problem,

I have a fixed sized div, and I would like to have a text (on top or bottom of the image) and an image inside it.

The image ratio must be respected and the image width and height are not known beforehand.

I have tried lots of things and the best result that I have is a text, my image with a preserved ratio, but the image is cropped.

Here is an illustration of my problem:

The HTML Structure:

[image: The HTML structure]

The Main Div:

[image]

The div containing the text:

[image]

The img element (we can see that image is cropped):

[image]

The image is cropped because it takes the width of the parent div, but the text div is also contained by the parent div, so it take some place...

EDIT: just to precise something: I add these elements dynamically with javascript, so when I set sizes, divs and images are not yet in the DOM (so I can't get the text div size to compute the img size).

What is the solution ?

Thanks :)

EDIT 2:

What I want:

[image]

Edit 3: the javascript code which generate the div:

```
    this.m_cellElem = document.createElement('div');
    this.m_cellElem.style.width = width + "px";
    this.m_cellElem.style.height = height + "px";

    var text = document.createElement('div');
    text.style.width = width + "px";
    text.style.textAlign = "center";
    text.innerHTML = this.m_name;

    this.m_imgElem = document.createElement('img');
    this.m_imgElem.id = "viewImg-" + this.m_viewUniqueId;
    this.m_imgElem.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.m_poster);
    this.m_imgElem.style.maxWidth = "100%";
    this.m_imgElem.style.maxHeight = "100%";

    this.m_cellElem.appendChild(text);
    this.m_cellElem.appendChild(this.m_imgElem);
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I tried lots of CSS/HTML combination to do that, this is my best result. There is not lots of code to write, it's, I think, a simple CSS solution, but I'm not a web developer and even with google search, I didn't find any solution.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include your code it would be most helpful.

Comment: My code only set the main div width and height, the text div width and text align and the img max-width & max-height, as we can see in the HTML structure. But I will add these lines of code if it's helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally works thanks to Antony SUTHAKAR J.

I just adapted his code like this:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.container', function(e) {
var mainDivs = e.target.getElementsByClassName("mainDiv");

    for (var i = 0; i < mainDivs.length; i++) {
        var mainDiv = mainDivs[i];
        var img = view.getElementsByClassName("img")[0];
        var text = view.getElementsByClassName("textDiv")[0];
        var imgHeight = $(view).height() - $(text).height();
        img.style.maxHeight = imgHeight + "px";
    }
});
```

Works pretty well. Thank you Antony.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the parent div does not have any 'overflow: hidden' property.

Set the inner div style

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

and the image max-height should not be 100%;
It should be the 'parent div height - the text div height'.
For example,
consider parent div height 100px and the text div height 30px then the image style should be

```
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 70px;
```

Try this, hope it will work !!!

**Editted**

Follow this working link, I hope this is what you are expecting.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/dm2jexo9/)

Comment: As I said in my first edit, I add these elements dynamically with javascript, so when I set sizes, divs and images are not yet in the DOM (so I can't get the text div size to compute the img size).

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` for your parent `div` instead of `height`.

```
<div style="width:276px;min-height:58px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cant do that because my div needs to has this size, not larger.